# New Developer Portal - Deprecated content detected

Tags: azure-api-management

Someone that left our company some time ago started working on upgrading our APIM developer portal from the legacy version to the current version. The changes were never published. I'm going to pick this back up again and am seeing an alert message when switching between pages. The message says:

> **Deprecated content detected** Your developer portal's content is based off the pre-production version of default content. Learn more about the problems it may cause and how to switch to the production version of content.

It contains a link to a bookmark that no longer exists on a page that still does:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal#preview-to-ga

I'd like to update the default content before publishing changes. Can anyone point me information on how to accomplish this? It looks like the new portal has been released for a couple of years now, so I guess that I'm not surprised that the bookmark and associated content have been removed. Hopefully the information is still available somewhere and I just haven't been able to find it!

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think I didn't ask my question very well and I've also learned more since posting it.

- What I learned is that we are not using the legacy portal at all. The new portal was deployed, but was not functioning correctly. The error I was seeing was being displayed in the new portal design interface and publishing updates did not seem to correct the issue.
- What I ended up doing was using the *Migrate* script in the [api-management-developer-portal](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/tree/master/scripts.v3) repo on GitHub to "publish" the version of the dev portal from one of our other APIM instances into the one that was broken. This essentially fixed the issue and got it to a point where we could work with it again.

Thanks!